# Euler's Theorem and Extensive properties

Tags: thermodynamics

I read in a textbook (Mathematics for Physical Chemistry by D. McQuarrie) an example of Euler's Theorem used in Thermodynamics. The author states "The [variables] are all extensive [quantities], and so [Euler's theorem is applicable]" (I'll provide more details below)

**My question**: why do variables being *extensive* indicate that this theorem is relevant?

**The theorem** starts by stating that a function is homogeneous to degree $N$ in some set of variables if those variables always form terms such that their powers sum to $N$. For example:

$$f(x,y) = yx^2 + y^2x + \frac{y^4}{x} + x^3$$

that would be homogeneous degree 3 for $x$ and $y$.

The theorem concludes with:

If $$f(\lambda x,\lambda y) = \lambda^N f(x,y)$$

Then $$Nf(x,y) = x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function#Positive_homogeneity)
is the wikipedia page for the same theorem.

**The example** uses the above theorem to derive:

$$U = S(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S})_{_{V,n}}+V(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V})_{_{S,n}}+n(\frac{\partial U}{\partial n})_{_{S,V}}$$

The author's solution immediately states: "The entropy, volume, and number of moles are all extensive thermodynamic quantities, and so $U(\lambda S,\lambda V,\lambda n) = \lambda U(S,V,n)$." After that statement the solution is simple.

I know that extensive variables means that they scale with the size of the system, but the relation to this theorem is unclear to me. I suppose that if the system is "twice as big" ($\lambda$ is doubled), then energy, entropy, volume, and amount are doubled. That still seems vague to me if its even a good way to think about this.

Comment: see https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/New_York_University/CHEM-UA_652%3A_Thermodynamics_and_Kinetics/Lecture_11%3A_Physical_significance_of_free_energy%2C_Euler%27s_theorem%2C_Maxwell_relations

Comment: Thanks, this part was especially relevant: "In fact, any extensive thermodynamic quantity must be a homogeneous function of degree 1 in its extensive arguments."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really is that simple. Stating that a thermodynamic system observes Euler's Theorem can be considered axiomatic if the geometry of the system is Cartesian: it reflects how extensive variables of the system scale with size. In a homogeneous system with a Cartesian geometry all extensive properties scale identically and so any extensive property can be written as a homogeneous function of degree 1 of the remaining properties.